# Deriving the equation for the traverse displacement of a string

Tags: homework-and-exercises, continuum-mechanics, string

> A semi-infinite string with one end fixed at the origin, is strectched along the positive half of the $x$ axis and released at rest from a position $y=f(x)$ $(x\geq 0)$. Derieve the expression
>
> $$y(x,t)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty} \cos\alpha(at) \sin\alpha(x)\int_{0}^{\infty} f(s)\sin\alpha(s) \,\mathrm ds\,\mathrm da$$
>
> for the transverse displacement. Let $F(x)(-\infty<x<\infty)$ denote the odd extension of $f(x)$ and show how this result reduces to
>
> $$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[F(x+at)+F(x-at)]$$

### What I tried:

The expression

$$y(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[F(x+at)+F(x-at)$$

which I know immediately as the de-Alembert solution of the wave equation

My boundary conditions are

$$u_{t}(x,t)=ku_{xx}(x,t)$$

$$u(t,0)=0$$

$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
Is my boundary conditions correct?

Then using separation of variables, i got

$$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$$

$$X(0)=0$$

and

$$T'(t)+\lambda kT(t)=0$$

The eigenvalues are

$$\lambda=\alpha^2$$

Eigenvectors are
$$T(t)=\exp(-\alpha^2 kt)$$

$$u(x,t)=\int_{0}^\infty \beta(\alpha)\exp(-\alpha^2 kt)\sin(\alpha (ax)~\mathrm da$$

I'm not sure of how to continue from here. Could anyone explain every step of the problem for me?

Answer (score 1):

$$u_{t}(x,t)=ku_{xx}(x,t)$$

Is in fact wrong. The 1D wave equation (PDE) is:

$$u_{tt}=ku_{xx}$$

This explains why you're getting an exponential time function, not a trigonometric one.

Start from $u(x,t)=X(x)\Gamma(t)$, insert it into the PDE, obtain separation and introduce a separation constant $-\lambda^2$.

Use the boundary conditions to determine the eigenvalues $\lambda_n$. This will give you expressions for $X_n(x)$ and $\Gamma_n(t)$.

That then gives, with superposition:

$$u(x,t)=\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}A_nX_n(x)\Gamma_n(t)$$

$A_n$ is determined from an initial condition and the Fourier series.